# PHP explode string

Tags: php, explode

I have this string: `0|DY1497ORYOSLDY932OSLCPH|1|0|0`

and I need to explode it like that:

`0| DY1497 ORY OSL DY932 OSL CPH |1|0|0`

```
$string1 = 'DY1497';
$string2 = 'ORY';
$string3 = 'OSL';
$string4 = 'DY932';
$string5 = 'OSL';
$string6 = 'CPH';
```

I searched, but all I could find is how to explode when the text is separated with `/`, `-`, etc. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the pattern ?

Comment: hmm the string does not look like having a common pattern even for regex. Do you have some pattern by which it should be seperated as asked by @BabyAzerty

Comment: your string always have same number of digit for `string1 =5`, `string2=3`?

Comment: Did you try `$resultArray = explode("|", "0|DY1497ORYOSLDY932OSLCPH|1|0|0")` to get rid of the numbers around?

Comment: I got this string from other website using Symfony2 DOMCrawler. Now I need to explode it and use it in next operations.

Comment: Looks like a flight route containing airport codes and aircraft numbers. This could be an interesting question, but @Ignas doesn't seem to be around anymore to provide additional details. I'm flagging it as unclear.

Answer (score 9):

The best choice is probably a regex:

```
if (preg_match('/|(.{6})(.{3})(.{3})(.{5})(.{3})(.{3})|/', $string, $matches)) {
    echo $matches[1];
    echo $matches[2];
    echo $matches[3];
    echo $matches[4];
    echo $matches[5];
    echo $matches[6];
}
```

This divides the string simply by length in characters. You may need to modify this as needed. See http://regular-expressions.info

Comment: looks awesome, but my string is changing dynamically everytime I choose other options. And count of symbols might change too.

Comment: @Ignas Well then you will just have to adapt the regex pattern to whatever it is you need.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use substr() if you know the exact position of the characters you need

Answer (score 1):

Son, it looks to me like you searching for some specific tokens up in this here string. What I reckon you can do is, make yerself one array outa little search patterns you might be a looking fer. Something like this here:

```
$patterns = array('ORY', 'OSL', 'CPH', 'DY[\d]+');
```

Then you can make yerself a nice big regexp outa that:

```
$regexp = '/(' . implode('|', $patterns) . ')/';
```

Then, what you gonna do is, use `preg_match_all` to find every one of them fellers thisaway:

```
preg_match_all($regexp, $string, $matches);
```

Now, you do that and then looka what you got in `$matches`. I'd wager it has what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of splitting up strings that consists of fixed length fields is with 'unpack' which is very suited to this job.

here is some tested code that demonstrates it:

```
<?php

$origSource = '0|DY1497ORYOSLDY932OSLCPH|1|0|0';

// expected result
$string1 = 'DY1497';
$string2 = 'ORY';
$string3 = 'OSL';
$string4 = 'DY932';
$string5 = 'OSL';
$string6 = 'CPH';

// get the string we are interested in...
$tempStr = explode('|', $origSource);

$source = $tempStr[1]; // string with fixed length fields
/* debug */ var_dump($source);

// define where the fixed length fields are and the indexes to call them in the output array
$format = 'A6field1/' . 'A3field2/' . 'A3field3/'. 'A5field4/'. 'A3field5/'. 'A*field6/' ; // make it clear where the fields are...

$dest = unpack($format, $source);
/* debug */ var_dump($dest);

?>
```

Comment: looks awesome, but my string is changing dynamically everytime I choose other options. And count of symbols might change too.

Answer (score -1):

firstly you have to concat your string with a special character like -,#,$ etc...

then you can explode it.

after that you may use the following syntax in php to explod string......

```
<?php

$string= "0|$DY1497$ORY$OSL$DY932$OSL$CPH$|1|0|0";
$pieces = explode("$", $string);

?>
```

For see your Result:---

```
<?php
foreach ($pieces as $value)
{
    echo "piece: $value<br />";
}
?>
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: This is not helpful at all